# Tab completion is not working in visual code studio

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tab-completion

im new in this programming world.

And i wanna asking a noobie question.

Im using visual code studio and trying make my first web project, so i install some extension so i can easily code(?). But when i using tab-completion its not really work. In my case, i use html and the tab-completion didnt really work like when u tab-ing or enter-ing its not complete all the code, for example i wanna type div, so i type [`<di`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqA6b.png) then tab/enter and its just showing [`<div`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQBjz.png) only, not `<div> </div>`  . And can anyone tell me how to fix that? Your answer really mean everything to me. Thankyou!

Oh! And here's my setting and a bunch of extension i use. Whether i should disabble or installing other

[My setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEYpS.png)

[Extension i use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewRYu.png)

[Another extension i use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDCag.png)

p.s. im sorry the picture not shown, i need to have 10 question so i can attach an actual image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the Auto Complete Tag and Auto Close Tag extensions:

- [Auto Close Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) for VS Code
- [Auto Complete Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-complete-tag) for VS Code

You can find additional Extensions like this by searching for the AutoComplete tag:
[Search VS Code marketplace for AutoComplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=tag%3AAutoComplete&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! But did the HTML Intellisen didnt work like the autocomplete? Because i instal it and the screen record shows it works just fine but in me it didnt auto complete :')

Comment: In this case try the Autocomplete Tag extension, I'll update the answer.